# Web based printing using jquery/php

Tags: php, jquery, printing

I want to create an HTML form which user can fill and print it on a network printer without installing drivers in the client pc. Is it possible? If yes how?. I am familiar with php and jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Server Side Printing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012936/php-server-side-printing)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is cloud printing.

If yes, you can look at [google cloud print](http://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/).